# Can not listen to parent from emitting child

Tags: vue.js

I can not listen to child event from parent, what is wrong here? Thank you!

```
// child component
<button class="button" v-on:click="doStuff">Operate</button>
methods: {
    doStuff() {
        this.$emit('flu');
    }
}

// parent component
<Product v-on:flu="test" v-bind:product="product"></Product>
methods: {
    test() {
        alert("A")
    }
}
```

Comment: Code looks fine. Works for me here: https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-dew-tci46

Comment: It's strange, here is my complete code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-ramanujan-j8t3w

can you have a look at it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using `this.$parent.$emit("flu")` instead of `this.$emit("flu")`

`this.$emit` will dispatch an event from the child to its parent component.

`this.$parent` is a reference of the parent component. So you are emitting an event from the parent of the child to its own parent.

The code in your sandbox is different to what you shared in your original post, so this is why it's hard to give you the answer right away.

Here is a working example (forked from your sandbox):

https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-violet-fu2p9